# <Text> tag in svg not rendering correctly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, icefaces

**Background**

1. The application UI is built in icefaces
2. As iceface works, a piece of javascript code is retrieved from the server, this code is run on the browser to update the svg element.Hence, svg is rendered
   dynamically for the 1st time

**Problem**

Issue is with the `<text>` tag in the svg not rendering properly. The `<text>` tag does not follow the positions x,y as mentioned in its attributes. Instead it just stays at the origin(0, 0) because of which each of the text within different `<text>` tag overlaps over each other.

[First rendering looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7DR.png)

However, the text gets positioned correctly automatically in the following cases:-

1. The size of the browser window is changed
2. Any of the elements in
   the `<svg>` tag is altered via the developer tool

From the above 2 points it appears that the svg itself is not rendered properly at the first load(dynamically). As soon as we do any of above 2 points chrome renders the svg correctly.

[Resizing windows/Altering any svg element in developer tool automatically fixes it to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syN41.png)

**Queries**

1. Is there a way to force reload svg in chrome?
2. What could be an alternative to using `<text>` tag for positioning text in the svg?
3. Any other solutions?

NOTE:-The same scenario works perfectly in Firefox !

Although the full svg code is quite big but here is the HTML piece responsible for rendering the svg text

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  height="100%" minwidth="1" width="100%" x="0" y="0">
    <g transform="matrix(57.22751322751323,0,0,57.22751322751323,360.6538835978836,26.883768888888916)">
        <g>
            <text font-size="1" style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; stroke:none; fill:black;" transform="scale(0.048895)" x="-10.779220779220779" y="2.1136363636363633">
                <tspan x="-10.779220779220779">Overlapping text</tspan>
                <tspan dy="1em" x="-10.779220779220779">Overlapping text</tspan>
            </text>
            <text font-size="1" style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; stroke:none; fill:black; font-weight:bold;" transform="scale(0.08001)" x="-6.587301587301588" y="-0.75">
                <tspan x="-6.587301587301588">Overlapping text</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: I have reportted the same on Chromium bug repo. Heres the [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673114)

Comment: Works perfectly on chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m.
Possibly a regression.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I think it's an issue with chrome (or chromium for Linux).

Just as a quick fix to get it working. My solution used Inkscape.

- First, make whatever SVG you want with Inkscape with the centered text.
- Then with the text selected press Ctrl + Shift + C. This will convert it from text to a path object sort of bypassing the chrome issue.

Not the best fix, I know but it works. Just a way to get it to work till it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue. But seems like this is due to the **late loading of font** used for text.

You can also try using two below properties:

**1. textLength**

**2. lengthAdjust**